# Convert grib files to text files with Python

Tags: python, grib

I want to read many grib files from a folder, and then save as text files.
The name of the text file will be same name as grib file.
My code:

```
import pygrib, os, glob

LAT1 = None
LAT2 = None
LON1 = None
LON2 = None

def process_message(grb, outfile):
    tmps = "%s" % grb
    wtitle = tmps.split(':')[1]
    wtime = tmps.split(':')[len(tmps.split(':'))-1].split(' ')[1]
    data, lat, lons = grb.data(LAT1, LAT2, LON1, LON2)
    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        tdata = data[i]
        tlat = lat[i]
        tlon = lons[1]
    for j in xrange(len(tdata)):
        wdata = tdata[j]
        wlat = tlat[j]
        wlon = tlon[j]
        outfile.write("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n" % (wtitle, wtime, wlat, 
   wlon, wdata)) 

os.chdir('/home/george/mona_modificat/data')        
filenames = glob.glob('*.grb')

for f in filenames:
        grbs = pygrib.open(f)
        grbs.seek(0)
        outfile = f
        for grb in grbs:
            process_message(grb, outfile)
            os.rename(outfile, outfile + '.txt')
        grbs.close()
```

When I run the code, I get this error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

`outfile` is a string not a file, glob returns a list of filepaths. You need to open it in `process_message`.

```
def process_message(grb, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w') as output:
        ...
```

Comment: Now, when I run the code, it's no errors, but nothing happens...no text file was created....